# InApp purchases with cordova

Tags: cordova, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins

I struggle with the inapp purchases with cordova.

I'm searching a good tutorial for in app purchases with cordova. Did somebody successful implemented in app purchases with cordova? 
If so, do you know about a tutorial or example?

I've tried many different plugins.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I hope these links should be helpful for getting started - https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase  https://alexdisler.com/2016/02/29/in-app-purchases-ionic-cordova/

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tutorials around to get you started:

- https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/html5-hybrid-apps-with-cordova-and-in-app-purchase
- http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/12570-in-app-purchase-mission-accomplished/
- http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/inapppurchase

I also recommend reading through the documentations of Fovea's cordova purchase plugin at https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase, it's very thorough, should teach you everything you need to understand.

Comment: Sir, pl. have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100306/j3k0-cordova-plugin-purchase-sandbox-mode-not-working) thread if you find time :)